# Issues while rendering textures in OpenGL in C++

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, stb-image, glad

I am having issues rendering textures in OpenGL. 
My goal is to render transparent and non transparent textures but the code I am using seems to swap and mix the pixels of my files.
I am mostly taking the code from [this tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Blending) (learnopengl.com) and I only modified a few things.
This is what I get :

[image: Weird pixels blinkng]

and this is what I am supposed to see:

[image: Normal rendering]

I did not use the same textures as the tutorial but they are the same format (`png` for the windows and `jpg` for the floor and the cubes)

I do not get any error message.

Here is my code :

```cpp
// main.cpp
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stb/stb_image.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include <blockpp/Shaders.hpp>
#include <blockpp/Camera.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int width, int height);
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow *window, double xpos, double ypos);
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow *window, double xoffset, double yoffset);
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);
unsigned int loadTexture(const char *path);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

// camera
Camera camera(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), {0.0f, 0.0f});
float lastX = (float)SCR_WIDTH / 2.0;
float lastY = (float)SCR_HEIGHT / 2.0;
bool firstMouse = true;

// timing
float deltaTime = 0.0f;
float lastFrame = 0.0f;

void debug_msg(std::string msg)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "[DEBUG] " << msg << std::endl;
#endif
}

#ifdef DEBUG
void GLAPIENTRY MessageCallback(GLenum source,
                                GLenum type,
                                GLuint id,
                                GLenum severity,
                                GLsizei length,
                                const GLchar *message,
                                const void *userParam);
#endif
int main()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif

    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_callback);
    glfwSetScrollCallback(window, scroll_callback);

    // tell GLFW to capture our mouse
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // configure global opengl state
    // -----------------------------
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

#ifdef DEBUG
    glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT);
    glDebugMessageCallback(MessageCallback, 0);
#endif

    // build and compile shaders
    // -------------------------
    Shader shader("shaders/default.vs", "shaders/default.fs");

    // set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    float cubeVertices[] = {
        // positions          // texture Coords
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

        -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    float planeVertices[] = {
        // positions          // texture Coords
        5.0f, -0.5f, 5.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f,
        -5.0f, -0.5f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -5.0f, -0.5f, -5.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f,

        5.0f, -0.5f, 5.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f,
        -5.0f, -0.5f, -5.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f,
        5.0f, -0.5f, -5.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f};
    float transparentVertices[] = {
        // positions         // texture Coords (swapped y coordinates because texture is flipped upside down)
        0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

        0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f};
    // cube VAO
    unsigned int cubeVAO, cubeVBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &cubeVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &cubeVBO);
    glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cubeVertices), &cubeVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void *)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void *)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    // plane VAO
    unsigned int planeVAO, planeVBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &planeVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &planeVBO);
    glBindVertexArray(planeVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, planeVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(planeVertices), &planeVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void *)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void *)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    // transparent VAO
    unsigned int transparentVAO, transparentVBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &transparentVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &transparentVBO);
    glBindVertexArray(transparentVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, transparentVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(transparentVertices), transparentVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void *)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void *)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // load textures
    // -------------
    unsigned int cubeTexture = loadTexture("assets/brick.jpg");
    unsigned int floorTexture = loadTexture("assets/floor.jpg");
    unsigned int transparentTexture = loadTexture("assets/window.png");

    // transparent window locations
    // --------------------------------
    std::vector<glm::vec3> windows{
        glm::vec3(-1.5f, 0.0f, -0.48f),
        glm::vec3(1.5f, 0.0f, 0.51f),
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.7f),
        glm::vec3(-0.3f, 0.0f, -2.3f),
        glm::vec3(0.5f, 0.0f, -0.6f)};

    // shader configuration
    // --------------------
    shader.use();
    shader.setInt("texture_atlas", 0);

    // render loop
    // -----------
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // per-frame time logic
        // --------------------
        float currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;

        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);

        // sort the transparent windows before rendering
        // ---------------------------------------------
        std::map<float, glm::vec3> sorted;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < windows.size(); i++)
        {
            float distance = glm::length(camera.Position - windows[i]);
            sorted[distance] = windows[i];
        }

        // render
        // ------
        glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // draw objects
        shader.use();
        glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(camera.Fov), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        glm::mat4 view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
        glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        shader.setMat4("projection", projection);
        shader.setMat4("view", view);
        // cubes
        glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, cubeTexture);
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f));
        shader.setMat4("model", model);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        shader.setMat4("model", model);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        // floor
        glBindVertexArray(planeVAO);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, floorTexture);
        model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        shader.setMat4("model", model);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        // windows (from furthest to nearest)
        glBindVertexArray(transparentVAO);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, transparentTexture);
        for (std::map<float, glm::vec3>::reverse_iterator it = sorted.rbegin(); it != sorted.rend(); ++it)
        {
            model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
            model = glm::translate(model, it->second);
            shader.setMat4("model", model);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        }

        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // optional: de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose:
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &cubeVAO);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &planeVAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &cubeVBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &planeVBO);

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(FORWARD, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_S) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(BACKWARD, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(LEFT, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_D) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(RIGHT, deltaTime);
}

// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int width, int height)
{
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

// glfw: whenever the mouse moves, this callback is called
// -------------------------------------------------------
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow *window, double xpos, double ypos)
{
    if (firstMouse)
    {
        lastX = xpos;
        lastY = ypos;
        firstMouse = false;
    }

    float xoffset = xpos - lastX;
    float yoffset = lastY - ypos; // reversed since y-coordinates go from bottom to top

    lastX = xpos;
    lastY = ypos;

    camera.ProcessMouseMovement(xoffset, yoffset);
}

// glfw: whenever the mouse scroll wheel scrolls, this callback is called
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow *window, double xoffset, double yoffset)
{
    camera.ProcessMouseScroll(yoffset);
}

// utility function for loading a 2D texture from file
// ---------------------------------------------------
unsigned int loadTexture(char const *path)
{
    unsigned int textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

    int width, height, nrComponents;
    unsigned char *data = stbi_load(path, &width, &height, &nrComponents, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        GLenum format;
        if (nrComponents == 1)
            format = GL_RED;
        else if (nrComponents == 3)
            format = GL_RGB;
        else if (nrComponents == 4)
            format = GL_RGBA;

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, format == GL_RGBA ? GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE : GL_REPEAT); // for this tutorial: use GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE to prevent semi-transparent borders. Due to interpolation it takes texels from next repeat
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, format == GL_RGBA ? GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE : GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        stbi_image_free(data);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Texture failed to load at path: " << path << std::endl;
        stbi_image_free(data);
    }

    return textureID;
}

#ifdef DEBUG
void GLAPIENTRY MessageCallback(GLenum source,
                                GLenum type,
                                GLuint id,
                                GLenum severity,
                                GLsizei length,
                                const GLchar *message,
                                const void *userParam)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "GL CALLBACK: %s type = 0x%x, severity = 0x%x, message = %s\n",
            (type == GL_DEBUG_TYPE_ERROR ? "** GL ERROR **" : ""),
            type, severity, message);
}
#endif
```

This is compiled with `-DDEBUG`

```c
// default.vs
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);
}
```

```c
// default.fs
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoords;

uniform sampler2D texture_atlas;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(texture_atlas, TexCoords);

}
```

```cpp
// Shaders.hpp
#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <blockpp/main.hpp>

class Shader
{
public:
    unsigned int ID;
    // constructor generates the shader on the fly
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Shader(const char *vertexPath, const char *fragmentPath, const char *geometryPath = nullptr)
    {
        // 1. retrieve the vertex/fragment source code from filePath
        std::string vertexCode;
        std::string fragmentCode;
        std::string geometryCode;
        std::ifstream vShaderFile;
        std::ifstream fShaderFile;
        std::ifstream gShaderFile;
        // ensure ifstream objects can throw exceptions:
        vShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
        fShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
        gShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
        try
        {
            // open files
            debug_msg("Reading shaders ...");
            vShaderFile.open(vertexPath);
            fShaderFile.open(fragmentPath);
            std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;
            // read file's buffer contents into streams
            vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
            fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();
            // close file handlers
            vShaderFile.close();
            fShaderFile.close();
            // convert stream into string
            vertexCode = vShaderStream.str();
            fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();
            // if geometry shader path is present, also load a geometry shader
            if (geometryPath != nullptr)
            {
                debug_msg("Geometry shader provided");
                debug_msg("Reading geometry shader ...");
                gShaderFile.open(geometryPath);
                std::stringstream gShaderStream;
                gShaderStream << gShaderFile.rdbuf();
                gShaderFile.close();
                geometryCode = gShaderStream.str();
            }
        }
        catch (std::ifstream::failure &e)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ" << std::endl;
        }
        debug_msg("Compiling shaders ... ");
        const char *vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
        const char *fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();
        // 2. compile shaders
        unsigned int vertex, fragment;
        // vertex shader
        vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertex);
        checkCompileErrors(vertex, "VERTEX");
        // fragment Shader
        fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &fShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragment);
        checkCompileErrors(fragment, "FRAGMENT");
        // if geometry shader is given, compile geometry shader
        unsigned int geometry;
        if (geometryPath != nullptr)
        {
            const char *gShaderCode = geometryCode.c_str();
            geometry = glCreateShader(GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER);
            glShaderSource(geometry, 1, &gShaderCode, NULL);
            glCompileShader(geometry);
            checkCompileErrors(geometry, "GEOMETRY");
        }
        // shader Program
        ID = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(ID, vertex);
        glAttachShader(ID, fragment);
        if (geometryPath != nullptr)
            glAttachShader(ID, geometry);
        glLinkProgram(ID);
        checkCompileErrors(ID, "PROGRAM");
        // delete the shaders as they're linked into our program now and no longer necessery
        glDeleteShader(vertex);
        glDeleteShader(fragment);
        if (geometryPath != nullptr)
            glDeleteShader(geometry);
    }
    // activate the shader
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void use()
    {
        glUseProgram(ID);
    }
    // utility uniform functions
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setBool(const std::string &name, bool value) const
    {
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), (int)value);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setInt(const std::string &name, int value) const
    {
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), value);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setFloat(const std::string &name, float value) const
    {
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), value);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setVec2(const std::string &name, const glm::vec2 &value) const
    {
        glUniform2fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, &value[0]);
    }
    void setVec2(const std::string &name, float x, float y) const
    {
        glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), x, y);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setVec3(const std::string &name, const glm::vec3 &value) const
    {
        glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, &value[0]);
    }
    void setVec3(const std::string &name, float x, float y, float z) const
    {
        glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), x, y, z);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setVec4(const std::string &name, const glm::vec4 &value) const
    {
        glUniform4fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, &value[0]);
    }
    void setVec4(const std::string &name, float x, float y, float z, float w)
    {
        glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), x, y, z, w);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setMat2(const std::string &name, const glm::mat2 &mat) const
    {
        glUniformMatrix2fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setMat3(const std::string &name, const glm::mat3 &mat) const
    {
        glUniformMatrix3fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setMat4(const std::string &name, const glm::mat4 &mat) const
    {
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]);
    }

private:
    // utility function for checking shader compilation/linking errors.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void checkCompileErrors(GLuint shader, std::string type)
    {
        GLint success;
        GLchar infoLog[1024];
        if (type != "PROGRAM")
        {
            glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
            if (!success)
            {
                glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
                std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER_COMPILATION_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n"
                          << infoLog << "\n -- --------------------------------------------------- -- " << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
            if (!success)
            {
                glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
                std::cout << "ERROR::PROGRAM_LINKING_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n"
                          << infoLog << "\n -- --------------------------------------------------- -- " << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
};
#endif
```

The textures I used :

`floor.jpg`

[image: floor.jpg]

`brick.jpg`

[image: brick.jpg]

`window.png`

[image: window.png]

Thank you in advance for your help, tell me if you need more code or details.

Comment: `shader.setInt("texture1", 0);` that's wrong. There is no uniform or sampler by the name of `texture1` in your code.

Comment: Please attach also the textures you used.

Comment: `glDepthMask(GL_TRUE)`, setting the depth function are missing. And do you even have a depth buffer in your framebuffer?

Comment: thank you @Ext3h I corrected `texture1` to `texture_atlas` (I use the name `texture_atlas` in my fragment shader). 
I also added glDepthMask and glDepthFunc but the result is the same

Comment: With the current code I can move around and there seem to be nothing wrong with depth testing, I don't really understand how my issue could be caused by the depth buffer

Comment: Then try debugging your application with Renderdoc. Take a look at the precise states at each drawcall.

Comment: @Ext3h i tried running my app in Renderdoc and I do not see where the error is, do you have any clue that could help me locate the mistake I made ?

Comment: Renderdoc won't tell you "hey, you got an error", but it does allow you to inspect your buffers, as well as the pipeline state on each of your drawcalls. Everything in the "texture viewer" and "pipeline state" tabs is of interest to you at you current level.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235996/discussion-between-liteapplication-and-ext3h).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just two typos:

`shader.setInt("texture1", 0);` has to spell `shader.setInt("texture_atlas", 0);`

`out vec2 TexCoord;` in the vertex shader does not match `in vec2 TexCoords;` in the fragment shader. No matching input makes `TexCoords` in your fragment shader undefined, giving you more or less "random" values.